# undefined variable in php

Tags: php, variables, scope, insert

i'm a newbi to php
this is my code.
i generate a random name , and store it in te variable $nome.
when i launch the query , it does insert a new record in my table ant, but, the generated name does not appers. what' s wrong whit my code?

here's my code:

```
enter code here
        <?php
require_once 'connection.php';
require_once 'config.php';

function getnome() {

    $nome = ['tyi','mii','pio','rin', 'bin', 'bik', 'riz','mil', 'pil','fyi','tri','din'];

    return $nome[mt_rand(0, count($nome) - 1)];


}



$query = "INSERT INTO ant (id, nome) VALUES ('id', $nome)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        if (!$res) {
            echo('<br>Error' . $mysqli->error);
        } else {
            echo $mysqli->affected_rows . ' created';
        }
```

var_dump (getnome());

Comment: You are not assigning a value to `$nome` anywhere in the outside scope, that variable only exists in your function. You want sth. like `$nome = getnome();` before you start to assemble the SQL statement. And go read http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `$nome` doesnt have any default value.

Comment: You are not using the getnome() function?

Comment: Are you putting the literal string `id` in the id-column? I'm guessing it's not a an auto incremented primary integer key?

Comment: solved! thanks to JayKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir please call your function that your created and its return random name.
Like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ant (id, nome) VALUES ('id','".getnome()."')";
```

Or Used Like

```
$MYCALL=getnome();
$query = "INSERT INTO ant (id, nome) VALUES ('id','".$MYCALL."')";
```

Comment: Roger!  Captan @MagnusEriksson agree

Comment: @AlessandroFlorean Happy To help You Sir. Roger Happy Codding

Answer (score 1):

it's about the scope of variables.

The var $nome only exsists within the function. See a function as a black box. You can throw something in (parameters) and you get something in return.

In your case you do not provide parameters. That's fine. But you should return something and use that.

You return $nome. But not the var itself, only the value.
so if you return $nome, you could have in your code:

`$foo = getnome();`
there is in the main program no knowlegde about the names of the vars inside the function

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
require_once 'config.php';

function getnome() {

    $nome = ['tyi','mii','pio','rin', 'bin', 'bik', 'riz','mil', 'pil','fyi','tri','din'];

    return $nome[mt_rand(0, count($nome) - 1)];


}



$query = "INSERT INTO ant (id, nome) VALUES ('id', ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", getnome());

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo('<br>Error' . $stmt->error);
        } else {
            echo $stmt->affected_rows . ' created';
        }
```

note: consider using prepared statements, to make your query saver

**edit** 
done by prepared statement

Comment: took the missing ' ' from ts code. Changed to prepared statement now

Comment: it does not works.Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\ant\indexant.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ant\indexant.php on line 18

Comment: mixed the syntax with pdo, which I use myself. Let me change the code

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
require_once 'config.php';

function getnome() {
    $nome = ['tyi','mii','pio','rin', 'bin', 'bik', 'riz','mil', 'pil','fyi','tri','din'];
    return $nome[mt_rand(0, count($nome) - 1)];
}

$nome = getnome();
$query = "INSERT INTO ant (id, nome) VALUES ('id', $nome)";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$res) {
    echo('<br>Error' . $mysqli->error);
} else {
    echo $mysqli->affected_rows . ' created';
}
```

Comment: ErrorUnknown column 'rin' in 'field list'--------- why

Comment: Yet another case of missing single quotes around the value.